# cannot create order due to missing prices

Tags: commercetools

I try to create an order from a variant and I receive this error:

> The variant '2' of product '27610ab0-d9cf-4685-87e7-de6e41fd7dd4'
>   does not contain a price for currency ''EUR' all countries, all
>   customer groups and all channels.

Why does it not work, I have already sufficient prices:

```
Currency   Price  Country   Customer Group
EUR        3.89   All       price
EUR        8.99   All       regularPrice
```

Comment: I suggest you put the product name (commercetools) in your question heading and in the question text in addition to the tag. In that way, other commercetools users are more likely to notice it and provide an answer.

Comment: The question was coming from an internal support request but this thing happens a lot of times.

Comment: @stenVesterli I cannot edit the title anymore

Comment: Oh yes. Well, anyway, for your next question ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message appeared because the customer assigned to the cart was in no customer group and the platform tried to find a price which does not require a customer group. But there are only prices connected to a customer group.

The solution is to assign the customer to the customer group "price" or "regularPrice".
Alternatively it would be possible to add a "list price" that has no customer group.